# ignoring html tags in angularjs filter search

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, filter

I need a little bit help. I'm using the highlight search for AngularJS from https://codeforgeek.com/2014/12/highlight-search-result-angular-filter/

My problem is now, that if I search for keywords the filter also the html tags displays.

In this example, if I search for "test" the highlighted result would be correct. But if i search for example for the "h" or "head" it highlights and shows the raw html.

Picture attached

example content in JS file:

```
$scope.posts = [
        {
        "id"        : "1",
        "title"     : "CMS Newsletter - 20/12/2017",
        "content"   : "<html><Head><body>testest test</body></head></html>"
        };
```

Current filter in JS:

```
newsApp.filter('highlight', function($sce) {
 return function(text, phrase, input) {
if (phrase) text = text.replace(new RegExp('('+phrase+')', 'gi'),
     '<span style="background: red; color: #fff;">$1</span>') // highlighting style css

   return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)

   };
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.text"  class="search_e_news" placeholder="search the newsletter archive..." />

<div class="inner-news">
  <p ng-bind-html="post.content | highlight:search.text ">
  </p>
</div>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4J24.png)

[image]

Can somebody help me with this. Im not that experienced with angular.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery / jqlite in order to remove all html tags using

```
$(YOUR_HTML_CONTENT).text()
```

So. I would modify your highlight filter to be something like that:

```
newsApp.filter('highlight', function($sce) {
   return function(text, phrase, input) {
      text = $(text).text();
      // ----^
      if (phrase) text = text.replace(new RegExp('('+phrase+')', 'gi'),
      '<span style="background: red; color: #fff;">$1</span>') // highlighting style css

      return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
   };
});
```